# In C#, can you use Reflection to find properties that don't have a getter?

Tags: c#

In C#, can you use System.Reflection to find properties that don't have a getter?

I have tried using different binding flags, but nothing seems to help.

Also, other questions/answers on Stack Overflow don't seem to apply because they all use getters (I.e. `{ get; }`).  If you find one that you believe applies and answers this question, please provide a link.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace PropertyInfoExample
{
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public string PublicProperty; // <-- reflection won't show
        public string PublicPropertyWithGetter { get; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass();
            someObject.PublicProperty = "doesn't make a difference";
            BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
            PropertyInfo[] properties = someObject.GetType().GetProperties(bindingFlags);
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                Console.WriteLine(property.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
PublicPropertyWithGetter
```

Note the **missing "PublicProperty"** from the above list.

Target .NET Framework:  4.5.2

Comment: Your "property without a getter" isn't a property.  `GetProperties` will return all properties, whether they have a getter or not.

Comment: `public string PublicProperty;` - this is a field, not a property

Comment: `PublicProperty` is a *field*, not a property.

Comment: `GetFields()` will return fields.

Comment: Can you provide that as an answer, Ed Plunkett?

Comment: That's not a property. Do you want to find *fields*, or do you want to find *write only properties*? The latter are rare, but there are ways to find them.

Comment: A property without a getter would look like this: `public string PublicProperty {set {/* some code here */} }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not what .NET calls a "property"; it's a member variable. In .NET, we call it a "field".

```
public string PublicProperty;
```

It's just a variable. No code involved.

A "property" has a `get` and/or a `set`.

Reflection-wise, you get fields with `Type.GetFields()`

```
BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;

FieldInfo[] fields = someObject.GetType().GetFields(bindingFlags);
```

As dasblinkenlight observes, a "property without a getter" can certainly exist, but it looks like this -- which is what most of us thought you meant, seeing your title:

```
public string PublicProperty {set {/* some code here */} }
```

Comment: `GetProperties` I think you meant `GetFields`.

Comment: @Abion47 I sure did. Thanks!